# How to Find the Nearest Places based on current lat and long using Parse API(parse.com) in android

Tags: android, geolocation, parse-platform

I want to find out the nearest places using parse API.When i enter a city name i have to find all the nearest places based on current latitude and longitude.My keywords will be there in parse database.Please let me know how can i do it.Here is the sample code which i have tried

```
//for finding the nearest places
    ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(17.5, -54.2); 
    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("Places");
    object.put("hyderabad", point); 
    object.save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try whereWithinKilometers, whereWithinMiles or whereWithinRadians

Check on the [ParseQuery](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/) in the right menu.

You code will look like something like:

```
ParseGeoPoint userLocation = (ParseGeoPoint) userObject.get("location");
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("PlaceObject");
query.whereWithinKilometers("location", userLocation);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() { ... });
```

Comment: where can i pass current lat and long?can u explain me indetail?

Comment: I'll try: 1- Get curretn location (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724533/how-to-get-current-location-in-android-application) 2 - create ParseGeopoint objectAndroidLocation with the current lat and long ParseGeoPoint point = new ParseGeoPoint(objectAndroidLocation.getLatitude(),objectAndroidLocation.getLongitude()); 3 use this ParseGeoPoint in the query as it is in the code.

Comment: i have a class named "Restaurant" in that i'm saving all the geopoints now based on current location,i need to get the near by restaurants which are already saved in "Restaurant" class in parse.how can i do it??